# ng-if not really as intended

Tags: angularjs, pug

I'm trying to make a page print with `Angular`, using `ng-if`.

```js
$scope.onBtnPrintClicked = function(journal, date) {
  $scope.printTransaction = false;
  $scope.current = new Date();
  window.print()
};

$scope.onBtnPrintTransactionClicked = function(journal, date) {
  $scope.printTransaction = true;
  $scope.current = new Date();
  window.print()
};
```

```html
<button ng-click="onBtnPrintTransactionClicked(journal, selected.date)" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-print"></i>&nbsp;Print</button>
<button ng-click="onBtnPrintClicked(journal, selected.date)" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-print"></i>Print 2</button>


<section ng-if="printTransaction" class="printable journal-container">
  <h1>PRINT</h1>
</section>
<section ng-if="!printTransaction" class="printable journal-container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">PRINT2</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

But when I try to click print/print 2 it's showing different page/content.
What could be the problem?

Comment: Better create a Fiddle Demo to replicate the issue. So that its easy to understand what you are trying to achieve and whats going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I could understand from your question is that you're trying to print the **current** page, however the changes performed by your `functions` aren't completely load yet, so you could use [**`setTimeout`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) to make a little delay, as below:

```js
(function() {
  angular
    .module('app', [])
    .controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl);

  MainCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];

  function MainCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.printTransaction = true;
    
    $scope.onBtnPrintClicked = function(journal, date) {
      $scope.printTransaction = false;
      $scope.current = new Date();
      setTimeout(function() {
        window.print();
      }, 500);
    };

    $scope.onBtnPrintTransactionClicked = function(journal, date) {
      $scope.printTransaction = true;
      $scope.current = new Date();
      setTimeout(function() {
        window.print();
      }, 500);
    };
  }
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <button ng-click="onBtnPrintTransactionClicked(journal, selected.date)" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-print"></i>&nbsp;Print</button>
  <button ng-click="onBtnPrintClicked(journal, selected.date)" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-print"></i>&nbsp;Print 2</button>
  <section ng-if="printTransaction" class="printable journal-container">
    <h1>PRINT</h1>
  </section>
  <section ng-if="!printTransaction" class="printable journal-container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">PRINT2</div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

**Note:** I don't know if these are your real `functions`, but you could simplify it and do it all in a single `function`.

Comment: Rather than adding a delay, have you tried using `$scope.$evalAsync(window.print)` ?